# pages.isFan returns incorrect signature

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working on a Facebook canvas iFrame application, and I`m going insane.
I am trying to check if a user is a fan of the page where the app is located, so that I can allow or disallow voting.

I use the following code:

```
function CheckFan() {
FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    status: true, // check login status
    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
});


FB.api({ method: 'pages.isFan', page_id: '145116742177104' }
    , function(resp) {
        if (resp) { $('#main_frame').show(); $('#non_fan').hide(); }
        else { $('#main_frame').hide(); $('#non_fan').show(); }
    });
}
```

This JS SDK is driving me up the wall, while calling the documentation "incomplete" is an insult to incompleteness.

Any input will be appriciated.

Thank you!
-Elad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been deprecated by Facebook.
A new Graph API alternative will hopfuly be available by the time we need to deploy the app.

For now I use FQL:

```
FB.api({ method: 'fql.query', query: 'SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid= ' + user_id + ' AND page_id=145116742177104' },
    function(result) {
        if (result.length)
        { $('.main_frame').show(); $('#non_fan').hide(); } else { $('.main_frame').hide(); $('#non_fan').show(); }
    });
```